# Locked out of admin and some pictures don't show after failed SSL installation

Tags: admin, htaccess, ssl, https

in a bit of a pickle here as I'm not sure what has caused the issue so hopefully somebody here can help me.

So I purchased the SSL certificate and but the folder with the files in onto my website.

I wasn't sure where to proceed from there so I just looked a few different tutorials and installed a plugin that seem it would do it all for you.

This was the actual tutorial. http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-ssl-and-https-in-wordpress/

I tried to reset everything I did but uncommenting this

```
define('WPHTTPS_RESET', true);
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything.

I tried both solutions in that tutorial, manually doing it and also trying the plugin. The problem started from where I put in the SSL host "www.secure...."
instead of "secure....."

Is there something in the DB that I need to change ? or .htaccess?